# Why is my jQuery popup box not "modal"?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, code-behind

I have this javascript:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-3.0.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    //Total out of range dialog
    var opt = {
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        width: 550,
        height: 650,
        buttons: { 'OK': function () { $(this).dialog('close'); } },
        title: 'This is a test'
    };

    function ShowRangeDialog() {
        $(function () {
            $('#rangeDialog').dialog(opt).dialog("open");
        });
    };
</script>
```

I have this div located inside a tab container:

```
<div id="rangeDialog" style="display: none;" title="Total out of range">
  <p>
    Your line items total is out of the range allowed by the approval level you chose.
    Please check the approval range and adjust the line items or quantities.
  </p>
</div>
```

And I have this code-behind:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("ShowRangeDialog();");
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "key", sb.ToString(), true);
```

When I run this, the "popup" displays as appended text to the bottom of the page.  When I click the 'OK' button it hides.  So, it's like it's working but it's not actually displaying as a popup like it should.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, i think i misunderstood your question. By `it's not actually displaying as a popup like it should` you mean no style is applied?

Comment: Yeah, it's just text appended to the page, and I was expecting a modal popup.

Comment: But you need to include relevant jQuery CSS file too. Do you?

Comment: Oy...  Thanks!  Can't believe I missed that!